# How to raise MouseClick event?

Tags: c#, events

Hello
I have read that events can be raised the same way as methods. Well it works for my custom events (I create a delegate, the event and I am able to raise the event by calling it).
However I am not able to **manually** raise events like MouseClick and other, it keeps saying that it must appear on the left side of the += operator. What is the problem?

Comment: There is no code to post.. Just try to raise this.MouseClick event manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I am certain you'll get other answers more informative than this one, basically you can't "raise" an event outside the class that contains it. MSDN has [this to say](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) about events

> Events are a special kind of multicast
>   delegate that **can only be invoked from
>   within the class or struct where they
>   are declared** (the publisher class). If
>   other classes or structs subscribe to
>   the event, their event handler methods
>   will be called when the publisher
>   class raises the event.

If you wanted to literally raise the event for, say, a Windows Forms Control MouseClick, you'd have to create a subclass of that control and either invoke base.OnMouseClick() or override it.

Comment: Gosh yeah, I think that is the cause :D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is a button, you can programmatically click it using the [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx) method.

Sadly, this only works on buttons and not other types of `Control`s... except `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to click button you should call:

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

If you want to call MouseClick please refer to this [forum](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/321029-how-to-simulate-a-mouse-click-in-c/), there is solution in c# using windows api:

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Enter your code here
}

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

    this.button1_Click(this, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to manually raise the event "click". This works for me:

```
public partial class CustomButton : UserControl
{
    public new event EventHandler Click;

    private void lblText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Click(this, e);
    }

}
```